# Can't access laravel eloquent property in blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm retrieving data in following way from controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
     $news = News::select('id','heading', 'body', 'image','category')->with('newsCategory')->where('id', $id)->first();
     return view('pages.news_details')->with('news', $news);
}
```

**News** model is

```
public function newsCategory()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category');
}
```

and I got a successful response

```
{"id":1,"heading":"Fugiat veniam nons.",
"body":"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
"image":null,
"category":4,
"news_category":{"id":4,"title":"health care","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}}
```

However, I trying to access it in blade file. All the properties are accessible except `news-category`. Here how I'm trying to access it

```
$news->news_category->title
```

`dd($news->toArray())` returns

[image]

But it's not working. How can I access the property in that way ?

Comment: The relationship is `newsCategory` not `news_category`.

Comment: dd($news->toArray()); before returning view and post it in quesiton

Comment: added @JohnLobo

Comment: try  $news->newsCategory ->title

Comment: OHH..! That worked. But a question it's `news_category` in dd but why `newsCategory` worked ?

Comment: credit goes to @Peppermintology. Even  at first instance i ignored that  relationship name. i was thinking about data will be null.

Comment: @OsmanRafi When serializing objects (`toArray()`) etc. Laravel converts `camelCase` to `snake_case`, unless you choose to override that convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting the model to array or json, laravel converts relationship names to snake case. That is why it is being shown as `news_category`.

In your blade file, you are still dealing with the eloquent object, so it hasn't been converted to snake case yet. Thus in your php code, you need to access it as `newsCategory` as that is how the relationship has been defined.

You can control this behaviours using the [static `snakeAttributes`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/952f84a3a5449a5f80190479240fce15bdaad558/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L118) property on the model.

```php
   \**
     * Indicates whether attributes are snake cased on arrays.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

As already written in the comments, you are trying to access the wrong property.

In you `News` model you defined the property `newsCategory` and not `news_category`. So the property `news_category` is not existing.

Switch your code in the Blade view to

`$news->newsCategory->title`

...then it should work.